# Solving MILP with NEOS server-variable will not display

Tags: neos-server

I have submitted a mixed integer linear program to `NEOS` server to be solved. I am using `CBC` solver using `AMPL commands`. My command file contains two lines:

```
solve;
display x;
```

When I used a small dataset to test it out, the results were emailed to me and the variable `x` was displayed correctly. However, when I used a much larger dataset, I got an email saying the job had completed, but variable `` `x was not displayed in the email or when I logged in to the results page using my job ``number/password`.

How can I get access to the solution? Thanks so much for any help!